# Is it safe to use a single Mongoose database from two files/processes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, mongodb, mongoose

I've been working on a server and a push notification daemon that will both run simultaneously and interact with the same database. The idea behind this is that if one goes down, the other will still function.

I normally use Swift but for this project I'm writing it in Node, using [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com) as my database. I've created a helper `class` that I import in both my `server.js` file and my `notifier.js` file.

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Device = require('./device'); // This is a Schema

var uri = 'mongodb://localhost/devices';

function Database() {
    Mongoose.connect(uri,  { useMongoClient: true }, function(err) {
        console.log('connected: ' + err);
    });
}

Database.prototype.findDevice = function(params, callback) {
    Device.findOne(params, function(err, device) { 
        // etc...
    });
};

module.exports = Database;
```

Then separately from both `server.js` and `notifier.js` I create objects and query the database:

```
const Database = require('./db');
const db = new Database();

db.findDevice(params, function(err, device) {
    // Simplified, but I edit and save things back to the database via db
    device.token = 'blah';
    device.save();
});
```

Is this safe to do? When working with Swift (and Objective-C) I'm always concerned about making things thread safe. Is this a concern? Should I be worried about race conditions and modifying the same files at the same time?

Also, bonus question: How does Mongoose share a connection between files (or processes?). For example `Mongoose.connection.readyState` returns the same thing from different files.

Comment: MongoDB is a completely separate service and most often running on it's own dedicated machine. It's nothing like "opening a file in different processes". This is a "database" and they are made for multiple processes acting on them at the same time. So "thread safe" really has nothing to do with the subject. Are the methods of writing you are using safe for concurrent operations? Then that is a completely different question which entirely depends on the code you implement. But your general question here demonstrates a lack of understanding of what databases are, and that you should research.

Comment: @NeilLunn now that I've demonstrated my ignorance, would you have any links or resource suggestions that would explain MongoDB/Mongoose in greater detail? I've been reading documentation all week and as many SO questions as I can but clearly it hasn't go me where I ought to be 

Comment: As noted you seem to be struggling more with the general concept of what a "database" basically is and does. In brief it's a lot different to a 'text file'. If you want an explanation then how about searching for such things as *"How do databases work?"* or similar topics. Such answers usually cover "books" and are not really suited to any meaningful response here.

Comment: @NeilLunn dude, I know it's not a "text file". You don't have to be so condescending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "safe enough."

The long answer has to do with understanding what sort of consistency guarantees your system needs, how you've configured MongoDB, and whether there's any sharding or replication going on.

For the latter, you'll want to [read about atomicity and consistency](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/crud/) and perhaps also peek at [write concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/).

A good way to answer these questions, even when you think you've figured it out, is to test scenarios: Hammer a duplicate of your system with fake data and events and see if what happen is OK or not.

Comment: I've read that bit on write concern a few times now but I fear it's as you say. Real examples will probably garner more information. Thanks for the links.

Comment: Here is the first write-up of a series of tests that hammer on a small MongoDB cluster undergoing network partitions: https://aphyr.com/posts/284-call-me-maybe-mongodb That should introduce you to some possible failure scenarios and how to think about these issues.